# Unable to setup geoserver WMS layer as a background map in Qlik

Tags: raster, wms

When trying to add a WMS layer from geoserver in QLIK, despite being able to see the list of layers from different links, these layers don't show on the map.

For example, when trying to follow this tutorial: https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-Documents/Setting-up-a-WMS-as-a-background-map-in-Qlik-GeoAnalytics/ta-p/1476666, even the link provided won't work, despite all steps being followed.

Is there a change to configurations needed?

Example:
When trying in Layer >> Add layer >> Background layer [Format WMS], in WMS setup, for example the WMS of Gulf of Mexico WMS: https://certmapper.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/services/geology/gulfofmexico/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

in QGIS: connects, but in QLIK it just doesn't establish connection.

This happens to other WMS links, but for the particular geoserver WMS service that I'd like the most to connect, when trying to do the "WMS setup", although I can see the layers in the WMS, they don't load into the map.

Comment: please try to tell us about what you have tried and what exactly is not working

Comment: just added further information in the question. thank you!

Comment: Did you try with just the service URL and no parameters ~ e.g. `https://certmapper.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/services/geology/gulfofmexico/MapServer/WMSServer?`

Comment: I did. Just tried the example you provided and it doesn't load at all. I thought initially this would be a problem with geoserver's certificates, possibly, but then when trying to add layers from different sources, this problem still appears. Other wms links work, like for example:
[https://firms2.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/key/f2fa75f09b164b39fdaa389a5a56d983/?]

Comment: Despite its name the `https://firms2.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/key/f2fa75f09b164b39fdaa389a5a56d983/?` service isn't a WMS, its a WMTS

Comment: For SSL certificate problems `certmapper.cr.usgs.gov` has A+ rating so you should probably discount that as an issue, ref ~ `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=certmapper.cr.usgs.gov&s=137.227.229.75`